# Different results using same query with DB::raw and Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm getting some unexpected results when running an Eloquent join query. I get two different results from using the exact same query. One running with DB::raw(), the second with Eloquent.

In the Eloquent query, the Users that matches the

`where squad_user.leave_time >= seasons.start_time`

are missing and will not be included in the result set. The users that matches the

`or squad_user.leave is null`

will be included, however.

That's the only difference in the results from the two queries. The raw query actually produces the desired result set.

What ***really*** puzzles me is, if I check the query logs, both Laravel's and MySQL, I get the exact same query when running both the raw and Eloquent query.

**Raw query** (the *actual* query i get from the query log when running the Eloquent query)

```
return \DB::select(\DB::raw('
        select users.*
        from users
        inner join squad_user on users.id = squad_user.user_id
        inner join seasons on squad_user.squad_id = seasons.squad_id
        where squad_user.join_time <= seasons.end_time
        and (squad_user.leave_time >= seasons.start_time or squad_user.leave_time is null)
        and seasons.id = :seasonId
    '),
    ['seasonId' => 3]
);
```

**Eloquent query**

```
return User::join('squad_user', 'users.id', '=', 'squad_user.user_id')
           ->join('seasons', 'squad_user.squad_id', '=', 'seasons.squad_id')
           ->where('squad_user.join_time', '<=', 'seasons.end_time')
           ->where(function ($query)
           {
               $query->where('squad_user.leave_time', '>=', 'seasons.start_time')
                     ->orWhereNull('squad_user.leave_time');
           })
           ->where('seasons.id', 3)
           ->get(['users.*']);
```

**Laravel's Eloquent query log**

```
select `users`.*
from `users`
inner join `squad_user` on `users`.`id` = `squad_user`.`user_id`
inner join `seasons` on `squad_user`.`squad_id` = `seasons`.`squad_id`
where `squad_user`.`join_time` <= seasons.end_time
and (`squad_user`.`leave_time` >= seasons.start_time or `squad_user`.`leave_time` is null)
and `seasons`.`id` = 3
{"bindings":["seasons.end_time","seasons.start_time",3],"time":0.38,"name":"mysql"}
```

**MySQL's general_log on the Eloquent query**

```
select `users`.*
from `users`
inner join `squad_user` on `users`.`id` = `squad_user`.`user_id`
inner join `seasons` on `squad_user`.`squad_id` = `seasons`.`squad_id`
where `squad_user`.`join_time` <= ?
and (`squad_user`.`leave_time` >= ? or `squad_user`.`leave_time` is null)
and `seasons`.`id` = ?
```

**MySQL's general_log on the Raw query**

```
select users.*
            from users
            inner join squad_user on users.id = squad_user.user_id
            inner join seasons on squad_user.squad_id = seasons.squad_id
            where squad_user.join_time <= seasons.end_time
            and (squad_user.leave_time >= seasons.start_time or squad_user.leave_time is null)
            and seasons.id = ?
```

I would appreciate any pointers here, as I am very lost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`where` binds 3rd param and treats it usually as a string, unless you tell it not to by using raw statement. `DB::raw` or `whereRaw` will work for you:

```
return User::join('squad_user', 'users.id', '=', 'squad_user.user_id')
       ->join('seasons', 'squad_user.squad_id', '=', 'seasons.squad_id')
       ->where('squad_user.join_time', '<=', DB::raw('seasons.end_time'))
       ->where(function ($query)
       {
           $query->where('squad_user.leave_time', '>=', DB::raw('seasons.start_time'))
                 ->orWhereNull('squad_user.leave_time');
       })
       ->where('seasons.id', 3)
       ->get(['users.*']);
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks alot. Can't believe I didn't spot the difference in bindings.

Answer (score 2):

Since Laravel Verion 5.2 you can also use [`whereColumn`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses) to verify that two columns are equal (or pass a comparison operator to the method):

```
->whereColumn('squad_user.join_time', '<=', 'seasons.end_time')
```